# Filter on dynamic unique combinations of columns in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have df1 as raw dataframe, df2 has unique combinations of A & B and Result is taking the avg of Amount col of each unique combination. See below:

[image]

**df1 -> df2**:

`Combination = df1.crosstab("A", "B")`
Now the filter can be applied using the values currently in df2, but the challenge is that df2 can be dynamic as df1 changes with time. Hence, filters cannot be fixed manually. (shown below)

```
Result = df1.withColumn("Avg", when(col("A")=="AI3 & col("B")=="AI5), avg(col("Amount"))
………...
```

Need to read and map df2 combinations to filter and get result efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the first dataframe, then use `Window`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('A', 'B')

df.withColumn('avg', f.avg('Amount').over(w)).show()

+---+---+------+----+
|  A|  B|Amount| avg|
+---+---+------+----+
|AI8|AI5|    75|50.0|
|AI8|AI5|    25|50.0|
|AI3|AI5|    20|20.0|
|AI3|AI5|    30|20.0|
|AI3|AI5|    10|20.0|
|AI5|AI3|    80|80.0|
+---+---+------+----+
```

---

I don't understand why do you need the dataframe `df2`. Just group by the `df1` and get the average for each `A` and `B` that is what you want. Group by for those columns already implement the distinct combinations of columns.

```
df.groupBy('A', 'B').avg('Amount').show()

+---+---+-----------+
|  A|  B|avg(Amount)|
+---+---+-----------+
|AI8|AI5|       50.0|
|AI3|AI5|       20.0|
|AI5|AI3|       80.0|
+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Sorry, the result I am looking for is df1+Avg column, so maybe ```df1.join(df.groupBy('A', 'B').avg('Amount'), 'left')```. Will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: Then you'd better to use the Window.